# Как поставить setFocusable(false) сразу на все кнопки в программе?

Tags: java, swing

У меня в проекте много кнопок (JButton). Для каждой кнопки завожу отдельный объект. Далее - хочу поставить на все кнопки setFocusable(false). Приходится добавлять 50 лишних строк кода( Может есть способ попроще? Через UIManager.put() пытался, но нужного ключа не нашел

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<JButton> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (Component component : frame.getComponents()) // frame - главный фрейм
{
    getAllBtns(component, list);
}
list.forEach(btn -> btn.setFocusable(false));
```

и вот сам метод **getAllBtns**

```
private void getAllBtns(Component component, ArrayList<JButton> list)
{
    if (component instanceof JButton)
    {
        list.add((JButton) component);
    }
    if (component instanceof Container)
    {
        for (Component c : ((Container) component).getComponents())
        {
            getAllBtns(c, list);
        }
    }
}
```

Суть - идешь по всем компонентам во фрейме ( рекурсивно), добавляешь в **arrayList**, далее берешь каждый элемент из этого листа и делаешь `setFocusable(false)`